# Where did Featured Questions go?

Tags: support

So, there used to be a link to show questions that have a bounty on them.  I'm realizing I can't find it now.

How do I see what questions have a bounty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the featured tab.

It only shows when there are active bounties. You should see it now that your bounty is active.

SE caches things hyper-aggressively so this is the kind of thing that may take a few minutes to show up.

Answer (score 2):

Aha!  "Featured" only appears when there are questions with a bounty...